# How prove $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = 0\iff\lim_{x\to 0}xf(x) = 0 $?

Tags: limits

Let $f:R \rightarrow R$ such that  $$| f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y) |\le |x-y|,$$ for all $x, y \in R.$ How can I prove that  $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = 0\iff\lim_{x\to 0}xf(x) = 0? $$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} x=0$, $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)=0$ implies $\lim_{x\to 0}x\cdot f(x)=0$

Comment: You can't prove this. What if $f(x)=1$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, and you'll have $|1-1-1|\le |x-y|$, and what?

Comment: From left to right the assertion is OK, but from right to left...it isn't.

Comment: then $1 \leq |x-y| \implies $ if you select two points less than 1 appart, the function $f$ cannot be used in the example.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Say $f(x)=1$. True or False: (i) $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$. (ii) $\lim_{x\to0}xf(x)=0$. (iii) $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0\iff\lim_{x\to0}xf(x)=0$.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I misread the question.

Answer (score 6):

$(\implies)$

Straightforward.

$(\impliedby)$

---

**Edit:** Following David C. Ullrich's comment, I turned the wlog assumption $f \geqslant 0$ into using $|f(x)|$ instead of $f(x)$ everywhere.

---

First note that substituting $x = y$ yields $|f(2x) - f(x) - f(x)| \leqslant 0$, so $f(2x) = 2f(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) \neq 0$. We will show that also $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} x \cdot f(x) \neq 0$.

Exists such $\varepsilon > 0$ that there are arbitrarily small $x \neq 0$ with $|f(x)| \geqslant \varepsilon$. Let $\delta > 0$. There is such $x \neq 0$ that $|x| < \delta^2$ and $|f(x)| \geqslant \varepsilon$. There is a unique $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{\delta}{2} \leqslant |x| \cdot 2^n < \delta$ and then

$$|f(x \cdot 2^n)| = 2^n \cdot |f(x)| \geqslant \frac{\delta}{2 |x|} \cdot \varepsilon > \frac{\delta}{2 \delta^2} \cdot \varepsilon = \frac{\varepsilon}{2 \delta}.$$

Thus $|x \cdot 2^n| < \delta$ and

$$|x \cdot 2^n| \cdot |f(x \cdot 2^n)| \geqslant \frac{\delta}{2} \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2 \delta} = \frac{\varepsilon}{4}.$$

Comment: Excellent. You might consider just writing $|f|$ everywhere instead of saying we can assume $f\ge0$; in the current version one (strictly speaking) needs to show that $|f|$ satisfies the hypothesis...

Comment: You're right, but I only need the facts that $|f|(2x) = 2 |f|(x)$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} |f|(x) \neq 0$, which are left as exercise. :D

Comment: Certainly - wasn't complaining, just suggesting that just writing $|f|$ everywhere might be easier to follow.

Comment: Ok, I see your point.

Comment: but we have had $|f(x)|\leq |x|$

Comment: @piteer How do you get that $|f(x)|\le|x|$?

Answer (score 1):

@David, I can't comment (not enough reputation), but $f(x)=1$ fails the first hypothesis at $x=y=1$.

Answer (score -1):

From right to left

If $x=y$, we have
$$
|f(2x)-2f(x)|\le |x-x|\Longrightarrow f(2x)=2f(x)\Longrightarrow f(x)=ax,
$$
where $a$ is a constant, and statement is obvious.

Comment: This is assuming continuity, I think. No such assumption is made here.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, yes, agreed, I'm thinking about it

Comment: @CameronWilliams, I can prove that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: No, you can't. There are even functions with $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ yet discontinuous.

Comment: @Adayah It's possible that he can prove $f$ continuous _assuming_ that $\lim xf(x)=0$. Those discontinuous functions you refer to don't satisfy this. (Any such function must be unbounded on every intervall.)

Comment: @Adayah, strictly speaking, I can prove that $g(x)=f(x+y)-f(x)$ is continous for every $y$